# How to deal w/ Tensorflow multiple versions/installations [Ubuntu, Anaconda, VirtualEnv]

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, virtualenv, ubuntu-17.10

I installed Tensorflow on my Ubuntu on a VirtualEnv. Soon I realized I can import Tensorflow on Anaconda (Jupyter notebook & command line Python), without even activating the VirtualEnv. Then I checked the TF versions `print(tf.__version__)`. For Anaconda I got `v1.1.0`, for VirtualEnv `v1.5.0`.

I started digging in Anaconda a bit and I saw a Tensorflow env lying there. I removed it with `conda env remove -n tensorflow`, but I could still import the v1.1.0 even though the "tensorflow" conda environment got removed from the "envs" directory.

It seems there is a Tensorflow package installed somewhere, but I have no idea about it. I'm not experienced in Anaconda, so I just tried to check if I can locate any TF related files in its folder structure without much luck (I only found a tensorboard binary in the bin dir).

So how can I identify and uninstall the TF v1.1.0?
Also, is there a way to connect/use my current VirtualEnv TF in Anaconda, and how?

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I identify and uninstall the TF v1.1.0?

Run `pip show tensorflow` without activating virtual environment. If it shows TF v1.1.0 uninstall it:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

If `pip` doesn't know about TF find it manually: in Python `print(tf.__path__)` or `print(tf.__file__)` and remove the directory.